# How to make: 'enter' typed in the textfield result in a break in the paragraph?

Tags: django

I made a blog app in django. But when the user presses `enter` in the blog creation form it doesn't work in the database

eg. if I type,

```
this is 

an example blog
```

in the database its stored as: `this is an example blog`

the `enter` I pressed to insert a break isn't reflected in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) filter when outputting text into your templates.

For example:

```
{{ blog.content|linebreaks }}
```

Also, you should use `models.TextField()` instead of `models.CharField()` when designing your DB models to accommodate multiple lined text.